# JQuery: How to text insert HTML ascii character?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following JQuery code:

```
$(this).text('Options &#x25B4;');
```

However, the ascii code isn't showing up on my web page. All that shows up is on the webpage is `Options &#x25B4;`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 40, accepted):

Use the `.html()` method instead of `.text()`.

The whole point of `.text()` method is to make the text appear exactly as it's in the string, with all tags and entities.

Comment: Found this really useful.  helped me

Answer (score 3):

If you use a unicode escape ('\u25B2') instead of the html escape character,
you can use the .text method.

Some users will not have a font that will display either version.

Comment: Yes it's a downside that `.text('\u25B2')` may be less supported than `.html('&#x25B2;')`. But one upside is that `.text()` is [safer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49396917/673991) than `.html()` if there's any chance the string could ever one day come from untrusted sources (e.g. user input).

Answer (score 2):

`&#x25B4` is definitely **not** ascii (ascii's a character code that runs from 0 to 127...!-) -- it seems to be a high-page unicode character.  What char encoding is your page using?  With something "universal" like utf-8, unicode characters *should* show up... if the browser has them in its font, of course.  With other encodings, such characters might just be impossible to transmit and show.

Comment: It's an arrow triangle. The crazy thing is that if I do within HTML "Options &#x25B4;", the unicode character displays. But if I do my code via JavaScript, the unicode does NOT display

Answer (score 2):

..or if someone wants to use just javascript:

```
var d = document.createElement("div");
d.appendChild(document.createTextNode("500"));
var euro = document.createElement("span");
euro.innerHTML = "&euro;"; //your character
d.appendChild(euro);
```

prints: 500€

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
$(this).html('Options &#x25B4;');
```

Output:

```
Options ▴
```

If you want to test it online you can check out this [website](http://jsfiddle.net/). (I liked it very much)