# add html character with jQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have the following jQuery

```
$("h1").text($("h1").text().replace(/([^\s-]{5})(?=[^\s-])/g, '$1&shy;'));
```

`&shy;` is supposed to be optional `"-"` + `<br />`, so I want it to be there in case someone enters a very long word as the title so that instead of being chopped off, it is split onto separate lines.

currently, it will change `"ThisVeryLongWord"` to `"ThisV&shy;eryLo&shy;ngWor&shy;d"` on the page where it should change it to

```
ThisV-
eryLo-
ngWor-
d
```

(assuming that the word needs to be broken at each spot)

what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [JQuery: How to text insert HTML ascii character?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2726935/jquery-how-to-text-insert-html-ascii-character)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using `html()` instead of `text()`, at least for setting the value.

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
$("h1").html($("h1").text().replace(/([^\s-]{5})(?=[^\s-])/g, '$1&shy;'));​
```

[Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/BJaEm/1/)

Comment: maybe I wasn't clear enough, but &shy; will do -<br/> only if it has to break the word. It will not always break it. see http://www.quirksmode.org/oddsandends/wbr.html

Comment: @Alex Ok, it is clear now. I haven't seen `&shy;` before, and was not aware of it.