# jQuery html() method a security risk like innerHTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, security

I recently was reading a JavaScript book and discovered using innerHTML to pass plain text poses a security risk, so I was wondering does using the `html()` jQuery method pose these same risks? I tried to research it but I could not find anything.

For Example:

```
$("#saveContact").html("Save"); //change text to Save

var saveContact = document.getElementById("saveContact");
saveContact.innerHTML = "Save"; //change text to Save
```

These do the same thing from what I know, but do they both pose the same security risk of someone being able to inject some JavaScript and execute it?

I am not very knowledgeable in security, so I apologize in advance if anything is incorrect or explained incorrectly.

Comment: You should sanitise the contents before using `.html()` (and similar functions). Look at the example I just created: https://jsfiddle.net/ayvx4ew9/6/. Also, worth to read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16860287/security-comparison-of-eval-and-innerhtml-for-clientside-javascript)

Comment: @Raptor thank you, since all I have been doing on my website is using `html()` or `innerHTML` to pass raw strings, I switched to `text()` and `textContent` as suggested. These seem to also enhance performance slightly from what is said in links, always a plus.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

From the **[JQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/html/)**:

> **Additional Notes:**
>
> By design, any jQuery constructor or method that
> accepts an HTML string — jQuery(), .append(), .after(), etc. — **can
> potentially execute code**. This can occur by injection of script tags
> or use of HTML attributes that execute code (for example, ). **Do not use these methods to insert strings obtained from
> untrusted sources such as URL query parameters, cookies, or form
> inputs. Doing so can introduce cross-site-scripting (XSS)
> vulnerabilities. Remove or escape any user input before adding content
> to the document.**

So, for example, if the user were to pass an HTML string that contains a `<script>` element, then that script would be executed:

```js
$("#input").focus();
$("#input").on("blur", function(){
  $("#output").html($("#input").val());
});
```

```css
textarea { width:300px; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="input"><script>alert("The HTML in this element contains a script element that was processed! What if the script contained malicious content?!")</script></textarea>
<div id="output">Press TAB</div>
```

But, if we escape the string's contents before we pass it, we're safer:

```js
$("#input").focus();
$("#input").on("blur", function(){
  $("#output").html($("#input").val().replace("<", "&lt;").replace(">", "&gt;"));
});
```

```css
textarea { width:300px; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="input"><script>alert("This time the < and > characters (which signify an HTML tag are escaped into their HTML entity codes, so they won't be processed as HTML.")</script></textarea>
<div id="output">Press TAB</div>
```

**Finally, the best way to avoid processing a string as HTML is not to pass it to  `.innerHTML` or `.html()` in the first place.** That's why we have `.textContent` and `.text()` - they do the escaping for us:

```js
$("#input").focus();
$("#input").on("blur", function(){
  // Using .text() escapes the HTML automatically
  $("#output").text($("#input").val());
});
```

```css
textarea { width:300px; height: 100px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea id="input"><script>alert("This time nothing will be processed as HTML.")</script></textarea>
<div id="output">Press TAB</div>
```

Comment: What does it mean by "remove or escape any user input before adding content to the document"?

Comment: @Alec Well, remove simply means remove the HTML, "escape" means provide the code for the character, rather than the actual character so that the actual character won't be processed. For example `&lt;` is the escape code for `<`.

Answer (score 1):

From the [`.html()`](http://api.jquery.com/html/) docs:

> By design, any jQuery constructor or method that accepts an HTML string — jQuery(), .append(), .after(), etc. — can potentially execute code. This can occur by injection of script tags or use of HTML attributes that execute code (for example, ). Do not use these methods to insert strings obtained from untrusted sources such as URL query parameters, cookies, or form inputs. Doing so can introduce cross-site-scripting (XSS) vulnerabilities. Remove or escape any user input before adding content to the document.

This is why `.innerHTML` is bad and why `.html()` is also not good to use on strings from untrusted sources, say if you make an ajax request to get some data from an untrusted third party. You should use one of the numerous methods [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6234773/can-i-escape-html-special-chars-in-javascript) or better still, a proven library function.